# Trying to combine a column from two different csv files into one list in python

Tags: python, csv

I have two example csv files to make it easier, where csvexample.csv looks like this:

ID   Text
1 'goodmorning'
2 'goodafternoon'
3 'goodevening'

The csvexample1.csv file looks like this:

Day  Month
17 'Feb'
18 'Mar'
19 'May'

I want the first column of the first file and the second column of the second file to be added to one singular list. So far I have the following code:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
columns = defaultdict(list)


with open('csvexample.csv') as f, open('csvexample1.csv') as a:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    reader1=csv.reader(a)
    next(reader)
    next(reader1)
    for row in reader:
        for(i,v) in enumerate(row):
            columns[i].append(v)
    print (columns[0])
    for row in reader1:
        for (b,c) in enumerate(row):
            columns[b].append(c)
    print (columns[1])
```

This gives me the following outcome:
['1','2','3']
['Goodmorning', 'Goodafternoon', 'Goodevening ', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'May']

I'm quite new to python and I kind of do understand why I'm getting this result, but I am not sure how to fix it. I want the outcome to be:
['1', '2', '3', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'May'] but nothing I try seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ex:**

```
import csv
columns = defaultdict(list)

res = []
with open(filename) as f, open(filename2) as a:
    reader=csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    reader1=csv.reader(a, delimiter=' ')
    next(reader)
    next(reader1)
    for row in zip(reader, reader1):
        res.extend([row[0][0], row[1][1].replace("'", "")])
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['1', 'Feb', '2', 'Mar', '3', 'May']
```

Comment: Thank you! this code gives me an error though:  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "new.py", line 12, in <module>  
res.extend([row[0][0], row[1][1].replace("'", "")])  
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: try with out `delimiter=' '`